# Phantomjs submit and download cpf

Tags: pdf, download, phantomjs, submit

I want submit with my cpf and dowload the pdf.
This is the code but is not functional.

var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open("http://www.samaetga.com.br/portal/SegundaVia.aspx", function(status) {

if (status === "success") {

```
 console.log("sucesso");
};
page.render("page.png");
   page.evaluate(function() {
    document.getElementById("cpf").value = "00000000000";
   document.getElementById("u_0_1").click();

});
  setTimeout(function() {
   page.evaluate(function() {
    console.log('vou printar');
  });
  page.render("page.png");
 phantom.exit();
});
```

};

Comment: PhantomJS cant download files at the moment.

Comment: Any program i can submit and download the pdf?

Comment: SlimerJS has almost the same syntax and function set as PhantomJS, is required to be run in windowed environment (whereas PhantomJS is headless and can be run on server) but uses Firefox as its driver and can download files. Also have a look at Selenium, it can use Firefox, Chrome as its drivers.

Comment: can you help me with smiler js?